# How to duplicate a live Magento site to local machine to test a new theme

Tags: php, database, magento, phpmyadmin, localhost

An associate and I have been given the task of applying a new theme to a preexisting live Magento site. It has been a huge hassle so far and here's the catch — we have no Magento experience! The company is no longer in contact with the previous developer that managed the first site launch. The experience so far has been daunting — to say the least...

I have downloaded a copy of the public_html folder from the client's FTP — as well as exported their entire database. From there deleted the local.xml file in app -> etc to initiate Magento's install wizard.

The database however, is an entirely different problem in itself. It's more than 1 GB, so when importing through local phpMyAdmin, it gets interrupted and asks to reupload to resume the process. At one point though it stops picking up where it leaves off — making it incomplete and unusable. So we've fallen back on using Magento's Madison Island sample data for now.

Given our nonexistent experience with Magento, are we just missing something? From what I've researched, Magento has a steep learning curve but I feel like we're making the process more complicated than it needs to be.

I realize I haven't gotten too in depth on specifics yet, I just want to make sure we're looking at this from the right perspective — especially given that our experience is mostly Wordpress-based. A lot of our process so far has been taken from online tutorials, articles, etc but with no luck yet.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

step 1 : copy entire folder that is within from public_html live server

step 2 : create folder name "magento" under root folder of your local machine

step 3 : import your database using cmd i'm using wamp server so type cmd in run manu navigate to where your install wamp,xmapp or whatever
now find some thing like this i have wamp so H:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin>
paste your live database ".sql" file here and run the following command 
H:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin>mysql -u root -p magento < magento.sql

here magento is the database name of your local machine while magento.sql is the copy of live dabase sql file

open up your app/etc/local.xml and find

```html
<default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[magento]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
</default_setup>
```

make sure with this settings that username, password are as your local machine

also after import db make sure with this open up your core_config_data and find following record

9   default     0   web/unsecure/base_url   http://localhost/magento/
10  default     0   web/secure/base_url     http://localhost/magento/

Let me know if you have still any query.

Comment: Hi, I have replaced the two entries in the database with local host URL's but when I navigate to local magento website in my browser it redirects me to live website. Any idea why?

Comment: Okay, Could you please delete cache folder which is in var/ folder of your root magento installation in local machine. if you still persist with issue add me skype : samumaretiya

Comment: Hi, I googled this problem and found other posts suggesting exactly that. Now I have my development site up and running. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad to hearing this. cheer :)